# Asynch Page Call From a Bookmarklet with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that will take the URL of the current page you are on, and send it to an application written using CodeIgniter.

The problem I keep running into is that I can't do a standard AJAX call, because it's cross-domain. It is disallowed, and I can't figure out a way to use the JSONP via `$_GET` method since CodeIgniter blows away the `$_GET` parameter.

At this point I'll take any suggestions on how to do this. Please note that I need to send a URL, and if it's to be passed via a URL itself it obviously needs to be encoded or something. This I also haven't figured out how to do, so any pointers on that end would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter unsets $_GET but you can get the data from the query string. It is a little inefficient because PHP will probably end parsing the query string twice, but it should work:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $get);
print_r($get);
```

All the GET variables should be accesible in the variable $get. See [`parse_str()` documentation](https://www.php.net/parse_str) for some more information.

---

As an alternative you could url-encode the current URL and append it to what you are requesting e.g.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/bookmarklet/' 
               +  encodeURIComponent(window.location);
```

Then in Codeigniter do something like:

```
//you might have to call urldecode() on this value 
$url = $this->uri->segment(0);
```

but you may find you then have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311801/url-encoded-forward-slashes-breaking-my-codeigniter-app)

Comment: Ummm...could you clarify a little there...I have NO CLUE what that is.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [enable query strings in Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), but watch out for the caveats - you can't use the URL helper, for example.

Comment: Good call...though it looks like it would require me to do query strings for the WHOLE site...which I would like to avoid...