# How do you pass a URL into a CodeIgniter controller?

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [url encoded forward slashes breaking my codeigniter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311801/url-encoded-forward-slashes-breaking-my-codeigniter-app)

This is my controller:

```
class Foo extends Controller
{
   public function bar($url) {
       echo 'hello world';
   }
}
```

If I pass in a normal string into the bar function, I see "hello world" printed out.

> http://website.com/index.php/foo/bar/argument

If I pass in a URL encoded string into the bar function, I get an error.

> http://website.com/index.php/foo/bar/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com

.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php/foo/bar/http://www.yahoo.com was
>   not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` to encode/decode the url, but you may need to add more character in your permitted uri config.