# Codeigniter put protocol in url query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you pass a URL into a CodeIgniter controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183745/how-do-you-pass-a-url-into-a-codeigniter-controller)

How to make this works

http://example.com/route/http://redirecturl.com

in codeigniter

I want create route that handling url, like http://who.is/whois/http://google.com

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do and post the code you're trying to get to work.

Comment: a dupe of many many questions

Comment: give me links what is solution

Comment: it will be flagged any second

Comment: Hey whats wrong with me? I'm noob here, I just want link of the answers

Comment: you could also search, and look at the similar question suggestions before you post something. I flagged it, just wait until a mod sees it.

Comment: Yes, then please give me, right keyword about my question, I've search about 2 hours in stackoverflow, site:stackoverflow in google, also other forum, I can't find right keyword for this question

Comment: Helping the OP out, he can't seem to find the question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183745/how-do-you-pass-a-url-into-a-codeigniter-controller

Comment: @Ilya , ty, but I want like this one http://who.is/whois/http://google.com :)

Comment: so whats the problem? How does the duplicate question not help you out? Use htaccess rules to remove index.php and follow the instructions in the question to get forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking to another controller in your project, use `site_url('path/to/your/controller')`. You can also use the anchor function, to create external links. 
Make sure you load the [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) before using the above functions, and all should go fine.

Comment: I want create route that handling url, like http://who.is/whois/http://google.com

Comment: @oknoorap I see. You'll probably need to use regular expressions in your route files. It's well documented on the user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html