# Codeigniter, sending data with url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a codeigniter Controller that has an index page that accepts 4 parameters like the followng :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($file_name = NULL, $PID = NULL, $Email = NULL, $password = NULL){
        if($file_name === NULL){
           $this->output    
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array("status"=> "failure", "message" => "The file name is missing")));          
        }else if($PID === NULL){
            $this->output    
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array("status"=> "failure", "message" => "The PID is missing")));
        }else if($Email === NULL){
            $this->output    
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array("status"=> "failure", "message" => "The email is missing")));
        }else if($password === NULL){
            $this->output    
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array("status"=> "failure", "message" => "The password is missing")));
}else{
$this->output    
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array("status"=> "success", "message" => "Upload Done")));
}
}
}
```

the route.php file looks like :

```
$route['Upload/(:any)'] = "Upload/index/$1";
$route['Upload/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Upload/index/$1/$2";
$route['Upload/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Upload/index/$1/$2/$3";
$route['Upload/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Upload/index/$1/$2/$3/$4";
```

I want to call the Controller index method an provide all data like the following:

www.mysite.com/Upload/myfile.csv/367/myemail@gmail.com/mypass;23!ù/o*

if I run it like that I get :

An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

What is the best way to encrypt each data and send them all within the URL like above?

I tried base64 but same issue, any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Man just change your `config.php`
put this on on your permitted chars

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=';
```

you can variate depending on what you need

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';
```

Comment: Can I allow all possible chars?

Comment: The issue is now if the password has a slash that will break the routes conditions so any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: first you close this problem (or at least upvote me =P ) then we work on the next one, kidding on your apache configs put this AllowEncodedSlashes http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes
Then try to enconde the url so the "/" becames a "%2F"

Comment: ok Sorry i just forgot to do it. So can you advice me please?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311801/url-encoded-forward-slashes-breaking-my-codeigniter-app

And that

http://codeblow.com/questions/have-to-allow-encoded-slashes-on-apache/